# unable to fix the lift side and and scroll right side in material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mern

I am using material ui ,I want to fix the left side fix and right side scrollable but its not working.I am trying in this way....

```
    <Stack direction="row">
                <Box sx={{ position: "fixed", width: "25%" }}>Left-side box content</Box>
                <Box sx={{ overflow: "scroll", width: "75%" }}>Right-side box content</Box>
            </Stack>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try adding `overflow: "hidden"` to Left-side box.

Comment: not working bro